# Attribute to indicate a member needs a memo editor

Tags: c#

I have a `Notes` property (or field) that needs an attribute to indicate it requires long text (memo field) which will end up being a `textarea` instead of an `input` in html.

What's the most conventional attribute I can use to indicate this to myself?

I tried

```
[Editor(GetType(MemoEditor))]
public string Notes
```

but there is no `MemoEditor` nor anything like it that I could find.

Note that this is just metadata I don't expect any framework to decide what html to make. I'm doing that on my own. I just want to comply with convention.

I don't want to make my own attribute. It's not that important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` will give you a textarea.

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Notes
```